# Вектор из из значений датафрейма на pathon

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм координат точек:
x  y z
3  4 5
7  4 1
и есть произвольная точка [1,2,1]
как мне преобразовать большой датафрейм и точку в массив векторов, то есть
`[[3-1,4-2,5-1],   [7-1,4-2,1-1],   [...]]`
Нужно это для векторного произведения с другим известным вектором через функцию np.cross().

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, и вам нужно вычесть точку из каждого вектора, то можно так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 7], 'y': [4, 4], 'z': [5, 1]})
point = [1, 2, 1]
res = np.subtract(df.to_numpy(), point)
>>> res
[[2 2 4]
 [6 2 0]]
```